# Is this triangle construction possible?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I must construct this triangle:

Consider the triangle $ABC$. Take $D$ in the line of $BC$ such that $C$ is the mid point of $BD$ and take $Y$ in the line $AC$ such that the lines $AB$ and $BY$ are parallel.

I constructed the point $D$, but I don't see how I can construct the point $Y$ without this point being $A$. Does another possibility exists? I don't see how.

Comment: Well, how can $AB$ and $BY$ be parallel? They have $B$ in common! This is only possible if $AB=BY$, hence $Y=AB\cap AC=A$.  - Maybe you rather want $AD\|BY$?

Comment: i think you transferred your problem incorrectly.